# overriding install4j finish screen text

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to get rid of the default text that appears on the install4j finish screen.  I've edited the finish components and added a multi line label to display the text I want however it just displays that below the default text.  Is there a way to get rid of the default text completely?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1) Delete the "Finish" screen, add a "Configurable banner form" screen instead and select its "Quit after screen" property.

or

2) On the General Settings->Languages step, set up a custom localization file, then open the built-in editor and click on the "Override messages" tool bar button. Search for the message you want to change and click on OK. Then you can change the text in the editor. In this case the keys that you need to override are "FinishedLabel" and "FinishedLabelUnix".